# how to select the row by using checkbox in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

### This is the `Units` Table:

```
<div id="table_header">Units</div>
<table class="gridView location">
  <tr class="gridViewHeader">
  <th><%= check_box("select", "all", {class: 'location'}) %></th>
  <th>Location Code</th>
  <th>Location Reference</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="<%= cycle('gridViewclickableRowDialog', 'gridViewAltclickableRowDialog') %> current_location">
    <td><%= check_box("select", "all", {class: 'current_location'}) %></td>
    <td><%= current_location_id %></td>
    <td><%= current_location.Lo_Reference %></td>
    <td><%= current_location %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### This is the `Selected Units` Table:

```
<div id="table_header">Selected Units</div>
<table class="gridView location">
  <tr class="gridViewHeader">
  <th><%= check_box("select", "all", {class: 'location'}) %></th>
  <th>Location Code</th>
  <th>Location Reference</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="<%= cycle('gridViewclickableRowDialog', 'gridViewAltclickableRowDialog') %> current_location">
    <td><%= check_box("select", "all", {class: 'current_location'}) %></td>
    <td><%= current_location_id %></td>
    <td><%= current_location.Lo_Reference %></td>
    <td><%= current_location %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Image `button` to push

```
<%= image_tag("blue_right_arrow.png", id: 'blue_right_arrow', :alt => "arro", title: 'Move to Selected Units') %>
```

By clicking this `button`, the selected row from the `Units` table should transferred to the `Selected Units` table.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: by `"how to use that check_box to select the exact row"` are you meaning to just highlight the row? Or any something else?

Comment: yeah, I meant by how to use that check_box to select the exact row and  to select all the row by clicking the checkbox in the header?

Comment: Do you mean how to catch the <TABLE> and <TR> DOM elements while the respective checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Modified markup**

```
<div class="table_header">Units</div>
<table class="gridView location" id="units">
  <thead>
    <tr class="gridViewHeader">
      <th><%= check_box("select", "all", {:class => "location"}) %></th>
      <th>Location Code</th>
      <th>Location Reference</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="current_location">
      <td><%= check_box("select", "all", {:class => "current_location"}) %></td>
      <td><%= current_location_id %></td>
      <td><%= current_location.Lo_Reference %></td>
      <td><%= current_location %></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div class="table_header">Selected Units</div>
<table class="gridView" id="selected_units">
  <thead>
    <tr class="gridViewHeader">
      <th><%= check_box("select", "all") %></th>
      <th>Location Code</th>
      <th>Location Reference</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody> 
    <tr class="<%= cycle('gridViewclickableRowDialog', 'gridViewAltclickableRowDialog') %>">
      <td><%= check_box("select", "all") %></td>
      <td><%= current_location_id %></td>
      <td><%= current_location.Lo_Reference %></td>
      <td><%= current_location %></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= image_tag("blue_right_arrow.png", id: 'blue_right_arrow', :alt => "arro", title: 'Move to Selected Units') %>
```

Note down the new classes added.

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  #copying the tr
  $("#blue_right_arrow").click(function() {
    $("input.current_location").each(function(i, el) {
      if($(el).is(":checked")) {
        $("table#selected_units tbody").append($(el).parent().parent().html());
        $(el).remove()
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Deepak. One more thing is i have a another table in the same page with the same table headers. But when i select the row from this table and i need to transfer the value to the another table by clicking some button. is it possible?

Comment: Sure, edit your question with the proper markup along the add button?

Comment: Thank deepak. I edited the question. Please help me to get this. Thanks

Comment: check it. Make sure you have the exact markup like what I have mentioned.

Comment: When i click the add button, it shows the error like `uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'parent' of undefined` on jquery line no: 6.

Comment: Yes, your markup for the second table is wrong. Check the markup, I have removed the classed from the second table.

Comment: yeah.. sorry. When i click the add button, it shows the error like uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'parent' of undefined on jquery line no: 6.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18103/discussion-between-deepak-prasanna-and-vinay)

Comment: oops, I always forget the brackets. check the javascript changes.

Comment: Its working Deepak. Thank you so so much for your support. Still i have some other issues. I will try to sort out that. Thanks.